# Is it possible to revoke admin permission using adb command?

Tags: android, adb, admin

As the title says...
Only thing I've found is to reach its settings screen, but nothing that actually revokes admin.

Some apps get admin rights by asking the user to do so, such as this one:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.universallauncher.universallauncher&hl=en

Before uninstalling an app like that, on some Android versions, you have to first revoke its admin permission. This is possible via UI, by going through the various settings screen, but I want to know if there is an easier way, in case I have a PC connected or have a rooted device, using adb command.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use:

```
adb shell pm [grant|revoke] com.my.app android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN
```

Let me know if it helped you!

I got some info about admin permissions in the 
[Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) site, hope it helps you.

Comment: This doesn't work. It says "Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.teslacoilsw.launcher has not requested permission android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" (tested on "Nova Launcher") .